# HMR not working with webpack-dev-server in reactapp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have following webpack configuration file:

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        filename:'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port:8080
    },
    module : {
        loaders :[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015','react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

The npm start section is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

On my computer, hot reload is working completely fine. But, with same configuration, it's not working on colleague's computer. Both of us are using ubuntu 16.04. We both have same configuration of npm and nodejs.

Edit:

webpack-devserver starts, but it's not hot reloading in case of my colleague's computer.

The versions:

```
npm: 3.5.2
node: v4.2.6
"webpack": "^2.7.0",    
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
```

Comment: Did you check the node and nom version with your colleague's?

Comment: Can you add more detail on "it's not working" ? Does the server start at all, does the webpack compilation crashes, etc ?